# SQL Query Groupby UserID and take the first and last for duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, hql

Hello I am trying to do a select of certain elements on a table. here is what my table look like Time,UsrerId,Data. Now what i want to do is for the same userid i want the first and last Value of data according to the timestamp.

Example:

```
Time UserID Data 
8 PM 1 200 
9 PM 1 300 
10 PM 1 100 
8 PM 2 150 
9 PM 2 250 
10 PM 2 350 
8 PM 3 100
```

So my result should look like:

```
1 200 100 
2 150 350 
3 100 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to this.

The first is to find the earliest and latest time for each userid. That you do like this:

```
SELECT UserID,
       MIN(Time) startTime,
       MAX(Time) endTime
  FROM theTable
 GROUP BY UserID
```

Then, you need to use that result to fetch the Data associated with the start time.  You do that by joining the above summary query (virtual table) like so.

```
SELECT b.UserID,
       b.Data startData
  FROM (
          SELECT UserID,
                 MIN(Time) startTime,
                 MAX(Time) endTime
            FROM theTable
           GROUP BY UserID
       ) a
  JOIN theTable b ON a.UserID = b.UserID AND a.startTime = b.Time
```

Finally, you need to cope with the end value in a similar way.

```
SELECT b.UserID,
       b.Data startData,
       c.Data endData
  FROM (
          SELECT UserID,
                 MIN(Time) startTime,
                 MAX(Time) endTime
            FROM theTable
           GROUP BY UserID
       ) a
  JOIN theTable b ON a.UserID = b.UserID AND a.startTime = b.Time
  JOIN theTable c ON a.UserID = c.UserID AND a.startTime = c.Time
```

This is a slightly tricky query because you have to join your table twice to get the two detail rows (start and end time rows) from it.

The "club sandwich" approach to building up your query should serve to make it clear how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Find the `min` and `max` time per `userid`

Then `Join` the result with main table with `userid` and `min time` to get the `min` data per `userid`

Then again join the result with main table with `userid` and `max time` to get the `max` data per `userid`

Try this.

```
select A.UserID, A.Data as Min_data ,c.data as Max_data
from test A
join 
(
SELECT   UserID, MIN(Times) AS Min_Time,
  Max(Times) AS Max_Time
FROM     test
GROUP BY UserID
) B 
ON a.UserID = B.UserID
and A.times = B.Min_Time
join test C
ON C.UserID = B.UserID
and C.times = B.Max_Time
```

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37ad9/14)**